# Update Trigger in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi Experts
I have table in sql server. and i want to apply update trigger on that.
i want to update the same table that have trigger.
can any one help me to with example.

Comment: Take a look into triggers documentation -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can find this code in SQL Server Management Studio Template Explorer

```
--======================================
--  Create T-SQL Trigger Template
--======================================
USE <database_name, sysname, AdventureWorks>
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('<schema_name, sysname, Sales>.<trigger_name, sysname, uStore>','TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER <schema_name, sysname, Sales>.<trigger_name, sysname, uStore> 
GO

CREATE TRIGGER <schema_name, sysname, Sales>.<trigger_name, sysname, uStore> 
   ON  <schema_name, sysname, Sales>.<table_name, sysname, Store> 
   AFTER <data_modification_statements, , UPDATE>
AS <T-SQL_statement, , UPDATE Sales.Store SET ModifiedDate = GETDATE() FROM inserted WHERE inserted.CustomerID = Sales.Store.CustomerID>
GO
```

A simple example being

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName ON TableName
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    /* Some SQL Statements */
    UPDATE  TableName
    SET     ColumnName = 'SomeText'

GO
```